# Latent covarying variables in SEM: Endogenous or exogenous?

Tags: covariance, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

in my SEM, I have two latent constructs that I regress towards an endogenous continuous variable (using maximum likelihood robust). The two latent variables covary. Are they endogenous then?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what the model looks like?
[image]

If so, the latent variables are still exogenous due to not being "*caused*" by anything (I say "caused" because you cannot make causal inferences from cross-sectional data). Exogenous variables can covary with other exogenous variables [(see Table 3).](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v048i02)

In fact, in the popular SEM R package `lavaan` all exogenous latent variables are assumed to covary by default.